# Chiswell/Hodges Exercise 3.5.5 -- Inequality for the number of truth values in truth table

Tags: inequality, logic, propositional-calculus

I have a hard time figuring out how an inequality is to be derived in Chiswell/Hodges' *Mathmatical Logic*. The Exercise is the following:

Let $\sigma$ be a signature containing $k$ symbols. Calculate 
(a) the number of $\sigma$-structures; 
(b) the number $\alpha(k, n)$ of times that you need to write either T or F in writing out a truth table for a formula $\phi$ of $LP(\sigma)$ which uses all of the propositional symbols in $\sigma$ and has $n$ nodes in its parsing tree; 
(c) the largest value $\beta(\mathcal{l})$ of $\alpha(k,n)$ given that the formula $\phi$ has length $\mathcal{l}$.

I had no trouble finding the formulas for (a) $2^k$ and for (b) $2^k(n+k)$. But I didn't find any way to solve (c) and in the solution of the book, there is the inequation for every $\mathcal{l}$, $\beta(\mathcal{l}) \leq 2^{(\frac{\mathcal{l}+3}{4})}(\frac{3l+5}{4})$ given with the additional information, that the maximum is achived when $\mathcal{l}\equiv 1 \quad (\text{mod} 4)$. I don't have a clue how to derive this inequation. Could someone please explain me how to get there? Thank you in advance!

==============================

Regarding the mentioned nodes, here some definition for parsing trees from the book:

**Definition 3.2.1** A (planar) tree is an ordered pair $(N,D)$ where

1. $N$ is a finite non-empty set whose elements are called nodes;
2. $D$ is a function that takes each node $\mu$ in $N$ to a sequence (possibly empty) of distinct nodes: 
   (3.17) $D(\mu) = (\nu_1,... ,\nu_n)$ 
   the nodes $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_n$ are called the daughters of $\mu$, and $\mu$ is called the mother of $\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_n$;
3. every node except one has exactly one mother; the exception is a node called
   the root, in symbols $\sqrt{}$, which has no mother;
4. there are no cycles, that is, sequences 
   (3.18) $\nu_1,\nu_2,... ,\nu_k \quad (k > 1)$ 
   where $\nu_k =\nu_1$ and each $\nu_i$ with $1\leq I<k$ has mother $\nu_i+1$.

**Definition 3.2.4** A parsing tree for $LP(\sigma)$ is a right-labelled tree where

- every node has arity $\leq 2$;
- every leaf is labelled with either $\bot$ or a symbol from $\sigma$;
- every node of arity 1 is labelled with $\lnot$;
- every node of arity 2 is labelled with one of $\land,\lor,\rightarrow\leftrightarrow$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us discuss the calculation over a parsing tree example from the book. The formula $\phi$ is $(p_{1}\wedge (\neg(p_{0}\rightarrow p_{2})))$, depicted as:

> [image]

So, the number of nodes, $n$, is $6$. The propositional signature $\sigma$ is $\{p_{0}, p_{1}, p_{2}\}$, that is, $k=3$. We have the truth table:

$2^{k} \left\{\begin{array}{c c c|c c c c c c}
p_{0} & p_{1} & p_{2} & (p_{1} &\wedge & (\neg & (p_{0} & \rightarrow & p_{2})))\\
\hline
T & T & T & T & F & F & T & T & T\\
T & T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F\\
T & F & T & F & F & F & T & T & T\\
T & F & F & F & F & T & T & F & F\\
F & T & T & T & F & F & F & T & T\\
F & T & F & T & F & F & F & T & F\\
F & F & T & F & F & F & F & T & T\\
F & F & F & F & F & F & F & T & F\\
\end{array}\\
\right.
\qquad\underbrace{\qquad\qquad\qquad}_{k}\underbrace{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad}_{n}$

Thus, the number of truth table entries ($T$ or $F$) is

$$\alpha(k, n) = 2^{k}n+2^{k}k=2^{k}(k+n)$$

The numerical value for $\phi$ is $\alpha(3, 6) = 2^{3}(3+6)=72$.

The length of a formula, $\mathcal{l}$, is the sum of the number of the nodes and the number of brackets. Each propositional connective, whether unary or binary, contributes a pair of brackets to the length of a formula. There are $n - k$ connectives. Therefore, $$\mathcal{l} = n+2(n-k) = 3n-2k$$

$\mathcal{l}$ for $\phi$ is $12$.

There are three types of nodes in the tree:

- the leaves,
- the nodes associated with the unary connective $\neg$,
- the nodes associated with a binary connective, which we may use $\Box$ to denote any one of them.

The case for the leaves which sums to $k$ is fixed. Consider a simplest negated formula $(\neg p)$. Its length is $4$ and its contribution to truth table is $2+2=4$ entries. On the other side, a simplest formula with a binary connective $(p_{i}\Box p_{j})$ has length $5$ and its contribution to truth table is $2^{2}.(2+1)=12$ entries. Hence, in order to maximise truth table entries for a particular length $\mathcal{l}$, a formula has to be composed of the largest number of binary connectives that $\mathcal{l}$ allows.

We can observe that length of a formula composed of only binary connectives is $2n-1$; other lengths in between entail that at least one negation occurs in the formula. Thus, we have

$$n =\frac{\mathcal{l}+1}{2}$$

and

$$k =\frac{3n-\mathcal{l}}{2}=\frac{\mathcal{l}+3}{4}$$

Substituting them into $\alpha(k, n)$ to maximise it, we get

$$\beta(l) = (2^{\frac{\mathcal{l}+3}{4}})(\frac{3\mathcal{l}+5}{4})$$

where the integral values of the terms (i.e., when $\mathcal{l}\equiv 1\pmod{4}$) correspond to the formulas composed of only binary connectives.